# rails 3 i18n set locale does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, default, locale

i would like translations to fallback to :en, but the default locale is :de. how can i achieve this best?
i tried in 'config/application.rb'

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.locale = :de
```

but I18n.locale is still :en after this.
any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you set locale like the following line

`I18n.locale = :de`

Then after the line triggered, EVERY visitor will using `de` locale, not the default locale `en`.

So the better way is

In your application_controller.rb

```
before_filter: set_locale

private


def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Reply to Jonathan Clark:

Every controller inherited from application_controller will set the locale.

Answer (score 1):

You cant set the locale in your environments.

you have to put default_locale in your environment config file and you have to set your locale in your application itself.

For example in your application_controller.rb

```
before_filter: set_locale

private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale]
  end
```

Comment: why does this happen?? The answer is valid, but the documentation says that changing those lines in 'config/application.rb' should change the locale.

Comment: Do I have to set locale on every page? I assume that you put the above code in the application controller?